# Ruby, what is the difference between a setter and initialize method

Tags: initialization, setter

```
class Account
  def initialize(starting_balance = 0)
     @balance = starting_balance
  end

  def balance #instance getter method
     @balance #instance variable visible only to this object
  end
```

```
  def balance=(new_amount)
     @balance = new_amount
  end
```

```
  def deposit(amount)
     @balance+=amount
  end
```

```
  @@bank_name= "MyBank.com" # class (static) variable

  # A class method
  def self.bank_name
     @@bank_name
  end
  # or: def SavingsAccount.bank_name : @@bank_name : end
```

```
end
```

I want to understand the code snippets in bold. What do they do? what is the difference between a setter and initialize method.
If I had an object test=Account.new() and why is test(30) giving an error. Isn't that suppose to call the setter method with parameter 30 and set the balance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initialize` is the method that is called on the newly created object when you do `Account.new` or `Account.new(my_starting_balance)`. In the first case `initialize` would be called with the default value `0` for `starting_balance` and in the second with `my_starting_balance`.

The setter method `balance=` is called when you do `my_account.balance = some_value` where `my_account` is an instance of the class `Account`. So if you have the following code, `initialize` will be called on line 1 (with 0 as its argument) and `balance=` on line 2 (with 23) as its argument:

```
my_account = Account.new
my_account.balance = 23
```

Of course in this case I could just as well write the following and not use the setter method at all:

```
my_account = Account.new(23)
```

However that doesn't always work because some times you might want to change the value of `balance` *after* the object has already been created.

> If I had an object test=Account.new() and why is test(30) giving an error.

Because `test(30)` means "call the method `test` with the argument 30" and there is no method called `test` in your code.

---

Regarding the second bolded part of your code: As the comments indicate, it sets a class variable named `@@bank_name` and defines a class method that returns that variable's value.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Learned something here.